# How to filter data in two different state when promise.all resolved?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, es6-promise

I send two requests to get

1- my services
2- admin services

when i got the response i set the state "myService, admin".

now admin services that contain my services.
So i want to filter if my services in admin service delete admin service from the array.

so I'm trying to using `new Set` but not works maybe i miss something

and another issue i use `Promise.all` to await the two request, but when I log the state there I got the initial state 'empty'

sample of data "my services and admin"

```
[
//my service
  {
    "id": 1,
    "img": ".....",
    "name": "service 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "img": ".....",
    "name": "service 2"
  },

  {
    "id": 3,
    "img": ".....",
    "name": "service 3"
  },
//admin service
  {
    "id": 1,
    "img": ".....",
    "name": "service 1"
  },
]
```

Code snippet

```
  const [myServices, setMyServices] = useState([]);
  const [adminServices, setAdminServices] = useState([]);
  const [allService, setAllService] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAdminServices = async () => {
      let AuthStr = `Bearer ${token}`;
      const headers = {
        Authorization: AuthStr,
        Accept: 'application/json',
      };
      Api.post('/admin/service', {}, {headers})
        .then((res) => {
          let {services} = res.data;
          let serviceModified = [];
          services.map((service) => {
            serviceModified.push({
              id: service.id,
              name: service.service_name,
              img: DOMAIN_URL + service.images_show[0]?.image,
            });
          });
          console.log('admin', serviceModified);
          setAdminServices(serviceModified);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log('err', err));
    };

    const getMyServices = async () => {
      let AuthStr = `Bearer ${token}`;
      const headers = {
        Authorization: AuthStr,
        Accept: 'application/json',
      };
      Api.post('/vendor/service', {}, {headers})
        .then((res) => {
          let {services} = res.data;
          let serviceModified = [];
          services.map((service) => {
            serviceModified.push({
              id: service.id,
              name: service.service_name,
              img: DOMAIN_URL + service.images_show[0]?.image,
            });
          });
          console.log('mine', serviceModified);
          setMyServices(serviceModified);
          setSelectedService(serviceModified); // for checkbox
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log('err', err));
    };

    Promise.all([getMyServices(), getAdminServices()]).then(() => {

      let allServices = [...myServices, ...adminServices]; // log empty!
      let uniq = [...new Set(allServices)];
      console.log(myServices);
      console.log('filtered', uniq);
      console.log('here i want to filter the data', allServices);
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);


UI

<FlatList
       data={allService}
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
       renderItem={renderMyServices}
   />
```

Comment: Declare `let serviceModified = [];` and `let serviceModified = [];` before this line `const getAdminServices = async () => {` ,it might help you

Comment: @EhsanNazeri sadly no! it still returns empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should return the promises from `getMyServices` and `getAdminServices`.

Also, setting state in react is async. So the updates to `myServices` and `adminServices` are not guaranteed to be reflected by the time you try using them. I suggest you return the results from the promises and use those values instead of the state.

Example:

```js
  const [myServices, setMyServices] = useState([]);
  const [adminServices, setAdminServices] = useState([]);
  const [allService, setAllService] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAdminServices = () => {
      let AuthStr = `Bearer ${token}`;
      const headers = {
        Authorization: AuthStr,
        Accept: 'application/json',
      };
      return Api.post('/admin/service', {}, {headers})
        .then((res) => {
          let {services} = res.data;
          let serviceModified = [];
          services.map((service) => {
            serviceModified.push({
              id: service.id,
              name: service.service_name,
              img: DOMAIN_URL + service.images_show[0]?.image,
            });
          });
          console.log('admin', serviceModified);
          return serviceModified;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log('err', err));
    };

    const getMyServices = () => {
      let AuthStr = `Bearer ${token}`;
      const headers = {
        Authorization: AuthStr,
        Accept: 'application/json',
      };
      return Api.post('/vendor/service', {}, {headers})
        .then((res) => {
          let {services} = res.data;
          let serviceModified = [];
          services.map((service) => {
            serviceModified.push({
              id: service.id,
              name: service.service_name,
              img: DOMAIN_URL + service.images_show[0]?.image,
            });
          });
          console.log('mine', serviceModified);
          return serviceModified;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log('err', err));
    };

    Promise.all([getMyServices(), getAdminServices()]).then(([myServices, adminServices]) => {
      // set state and do stuff
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Comment: Awesome! it's log data very well, but about my stuff :"D 
as I say before `Set` not works as expected can u please check out it?

Comment: Hey again, when u `return Api.post(...)` that's mean here it returns promise? and when return `serviceModified` that's for data in `.then`? and why in then get data in array `([myServices, adminServices])`

Comment: Yes, it returns the promise. Yes, when you return `serviceModified` it's for `then`. It's an array because Promise.all passes through an array. [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `promises.all` wrongly.

Ideally `promises.all` can await only if all the functions return you promises, but in your case, you are returning `undefined`.

Hence even before the API call is responding `Promises.all` will complete the execution and `then` is executed as well.

you can restructure your code to something like below,
(still, I see a lot of room for refactoring).

```js
  const [myServices, setMyServices] = useState([]);
  const [adminServices, setAdminServices] = useState([]);
  const [allService, setAllService] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAdminServices = async () => {
      let AuthStr = `Bearer ${token}`;
      const headers = {
        Authorization: AuthStr,
        Accept: 'application/json',
      };
      return Api.post('/admin/service', {}, {headers});
    };

    const setMyServices = (res) => {
       let {services} = res.data;
       let serviceModified = [];
       services.map((service) => {
       serviceModified.push({
           id: service.id,
           name: service.service_name,
           img: DOMAIN_URL + service.images_show[0]?.image,
          });
       });
       console.log('mine', serviceModified);
       setMyServices(serviceModified);
       setSelectedService(serviceModified); // for checkbox
       return serviceModified;
    }
    
    const setAdminServices = (res) => {
       let {services} = res.data;
       let serviceModified = [];
       services.map((service) => {
            serviceModified.push({
              id: service.id,
              name: service.service_name,
              img: DOMAIN_URL + service.images_show[0]?.image,
            });
          });
          console.log('admin', serviceModified);
          setAdminServices(serviceModified);
       return serviceModified;
     }  


    const getMyServices = async () => {
      let AuthStr = `Bearer ${token}`;
      const headers = {
        Authorization: AuthStr,
        Accept: 'application/json',
      };
      return Api.post('/vendor/service', {}, {headers});
    };

    Promise.all([getMyServices(), getAdminServices()]).then((data) => {
      console.log(data); // will have [myServiceResponse, adminServiceReponse];
      const myServices = setMyServices(data[0]);
      const adminServices = setAdminServices(data[1]);
      let allServices = [...myServices, ...adminServices]; // log empty!
      // set doesn't work this way, use `uniq` utility function from `lodash` or develop a custom one if required.
      let uniq = [...new Set(allServices)];
      console.log(myServices);
      console.log('filtered', uniq);
      console.log('here i want to filter the data', allServices);
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but @L Lawliet Answer it's a little simple/mini :)